# Integration on $R^d$ about Changing Coordinate

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis

> I have the formula $$\int_{\mathbb R^d}
>  F(x)dx=\int_{S^{d-1}}\int_0^\infty
>  F(r\gamma)r^{d-1}drd\sigma(\gamma)$$
>
> **Problem:** Apply this to $F(x)=g(r)f(\gamma)$, where $x=r\gamma$, to prove that for any rotation $R$, one has $$\int_{\mathbb R^d}
>  f(R(\gamma))d\sigma(\gamma)=\int_{S^{d-1}}f(\gamma)d\sigma(\gamma)$$
>
> Rotation in $\mathbb R^d$ is  a linear transformation $R:\mathbb
>  R^d\rightarrow \mathbb R^d$ which preserves the inner product.  Thus,
>   $$R(ax+by)=aR(x)+bR(y) $$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$ and $a,b\in
>  \mathbb R$. Also, $$R(x)\cdot R(y)=x\cdot y$$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb
>  R^d$

I don't know how to choose $g$. Can I get some hints?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the second displayed equation. How can $\mathrm d\sigma(\gamma)$ be integrated over $\mathbb R^d$ on the left but over $S^{d-1}$ on the right?

Comment: In case d=2, then $\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x)dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty f(rcos\theta,rsin\theta)rdrd\theta$. In this case, $\int_S^1 g(\gamma)d\sigma(\gamma)=\int_0^2\pi g(cos\theta,sin\theta)d\theta$.

Comment: That leaves me more rather than less confused. What does $\int_S^1$ denote? And what does all this have to do with my question? There's no integral of the form of the left-hand side of the second displayed equation in that comment.

Comment: Sorry.... This notation is wrong.  $\int_\mathbb{S^1}$

Comment: I get the impression that it's merely a typo in the question. It sounds like it should say $S^{d-1}$ where it says $\mathbb R^d$. If not, I really can't see why you're now writing $\mathbb S^1$ instead and never refer to the notation that I actually asked about.